# Extract Inline-IF items

Tags: javascript, json, regex, conditional-operator

How can I extract parts of (multi-line) inline-if that was written in javascript code like this one:

```
 ( MYDATA.FIELD > 1.03 ? 'higher than' : ( 0.97 > MYDATA.FIELD ? 'lower than' : 'equal to' ))+

 groups:

 "MYDATA.FIELD > 1.03" ,
 "'higher than'" ,
 "0.97 > MYDATA.FIELD" ,
 "'lower than'" ,
 "'equal to'"
```

for two inline-if in one line, i had this regex:

```
\((.*?)\s?\?(.*?)\:\s*(\((.*?)\s?\?(.*?)\:(.*?)\))\s?\)
```

or

```
 ( Condition1 == true || condition2 == 0.2 ) ?
  {"type":"text","value":"..."},
  {"type":"text","value":"..."},
  {"type":"text","value":"..."},
  :
  {"type":"text","value":"..."},
  {"type":"text","value":"..."},
 ) + ...

 groups:
 "Condition1 == true || condition2 == 0.2" ,

 "{"type":"text","value":"..."},
 {"type":"text","value":"..."},
 {"type":"text","value":"..."}," ,

 "{"type":"text","value":"..."},
 {"type":"text","value":"..."}," ,
```

I'm going to edit my javascript code and make json objects, so **no** replace function in javascript needed!

Maximum depth: 2

Comment: show the expected results for the above inputs

Comment: extracting `condition` , `truePart` and `falsePart` added to question, @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question about parsing or extracting items of inline-if or [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is done by this regex and story!

First, I've done in pcre(PHP) regex tester, because usages of IF-Clause in Regex or Conditional Capturing Groups or any thing you names, but known as `(?(-1)true|false)`

Thanks to Regex101 and it's brief definition:

> (?(1)yes|no)
>
> If capturing group 1 was matched so far, matches the pattern before the vertical bar. Otherwise, matches the pattern after the vertical bar. A group name, or a relative position (-1) in PCRE, can be used. Global flag breaks conditionals.

By this Regex 3 parts of inline If extracting: *(enters and spaces are for better readability)*

```
\(\s*
(.+?)\s*\?\s*
    (\(\s*)? (?(-1)(.+?)\s*\)|(.+?))
    \s*\:\s*
    (\(\s*)? (?(-1)(.+?)\s*\)|(.+?))
\s*\)
```

[Demo for Above Code](https://regex101.com/r/V01abt/1) and [Improvements in next update](https://regex101.com/r/V01abt/1) :

- For multi line accepting I changed `.` to `[^\X]` because *pcre* do not accepts usage of `[^]` ...
- Capturing groups where different in nested `inline-if`s, but it was not matter!

---

Now back home! but, what's **JavaScript** IF-Clause in Regex?

Converting `(\(\s*)? (?(-1)(.+?)\s*\)|(.+?))` to JavaScript Regex pattern is done by two usage of negative and positive looks: (thanks to [existing Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022635/i-would-like-to-mimick-conditionals-in-javascript-regex) and [others](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html))

> ((?=conditional-pattern)yes-pattern|(?!conditional-pattern)no-pattern)

```
      ( (?=\(\s*) .+?\) | (?!\(\s*) .+? )
Condition^^^^^^^  ^^^true           ^^^false
```

Final regex for extracting `inline-if` is: *(enters and spaces are for better readability)*

```
\(\s*
([^]+?)\s*\?\s*
    ((?=\(\s*)[^]+?\)|(?!\(\s*)[^]+?)
        \s+\:\s+
    ((?=\(\s*)[^]+?\)|(?!\(\s*)[^]+?)
\s*\)
```

- thanks to `{"type":"text","value":"..."},` that has not `:` and usage of `\s+\:\s+` solves my multi line search through json object definitions and finding `false` part.

[Demo for Final Answer](https://regex101.com/r/V01abt/3)